# Banned from flagging due to old(er) flags that were recently acted on

Tags: discussion, support

Today I went to flag a post and got a message that too many of my recent flags were declined, and I'm banned from flagging (not at issue here). I went to look at the declined flags in the last 7 days, shown below, and realized that only 2 of the flags were from the last 7 days. The other was from 10 days ago, but I guess was just acted on in the last 7 days, triggering the flag ban.

[image: flags in last 7 days]

Why is this (seemingly) based entirely on when the flag was acted on, rather than the age of the flag itself?

Answer (score 3):

The three flags you've shown here are all flags to close questions. Since you have less that 3,000 rep, this puts the question into the [Close Votes review queue](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/close/) (note: 3,000 rep needed to access this queue) for people with that rep to review and decide whether to close it or leave it open.

Once it's in the review queue, it will stay there until cleared by enough "close" or "leave open" votes. If the eventual disposition is "leave open", then your flag to close will show up as declined.

In the case of your flag from November 20<sup>th</sup>, it was declined earlier today on November 30<sup>th</sup>; there's no way that the system could know at the time you cast it what the eventual outcome would be. That's why it's based on the time the flag was cleared, not when it was cast.

Comment: I realize the system couldn't know ahead of time what the outcome would be. I guess I'm wondering if less weight should be given to declined flags that took so long to have an outcome? I could forsee a user with a bunch of old flags that all get voted on at the same time (perhaps by a user who just hit 3000 rep?), triggering a ban flag, even if those flags were spread out over months and months, and the user had all helpful flags otherwise. Or maybe I'm worrying over nothing...